# Recuperar dimensões de matriz em Python

Tags: python

Alguém pode me ajudar a escrever a função "dimensoes(matriz)" que receba uma matriz como parâmetro e imprima as dimensões da matriz recebida, no formato iXj?

```
def crie_matriz(n_linhas, n_colunas, valor):

    matriz = []

    for i in range(n_linhas):
        linha = []

        for j in range(n_colunas):
            linha.append(valor)
            matriz.append(linha)
    for n in matriz:
        print(''.join(map(str,matriz)))
    return matriz

a = crie_matriz(2,3)

print(a)
```

O código acima que fiz imprime a saída, mas a questão pede para imprimir a dimensão conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
minha_matriz = [[1], [2], [3]]
dimensoes(minha_matriz)
3X1

minha_matriz = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
dimensoes(minha_matriz)
2X3
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens sff

Comment: @Miguel adicionei o código que fiz, mas tá incompleto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código ficaria assim:

```
def dimensoes(matriz):
tam_matriz = (len(matriz), len(matriz[0]))
print('{}X{}'.format(tam_matriz[0], tam_matriz[1]))
```

Se a questão pede para imprimir, tem que usar o comando 'print', se pede para retornar ou devolver, use o comando 'return'

Comment: Olá Eduardo Oliveira, tentei como vc falou inseri a variavel e o print, substituindo o "print(''.join(map(str,matriz)))" pelo "tam_matriz = (len(matriz), len(matriz[0]))
print('{}X{}'.format(tam_matriz[0], tam_matriz[1]))". Porém não está dando certo. Por exemplo quando chamo a função "cria_matrizes(2,2,0), o código tá imprimindo "4x2" quatros vezes. Qual o erro do meu código?

Comment: O código é exatamente esse que você pediu, nada mais. Se está pedindo para criar uma função 'dimensoes', não vai ser necessário essa função 'cria_matrizes' que você citou.

Answer (score 2):

pode usar a biblioteca `numpy`, que ja vem com o método de retornar as dimensões da matriz/array

ex:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([[0, 1, 2],
          [3, 4, 5]]).shape
```

imprime `(2,3)`

que quando armazenado em uma variavel vc sempre pode chamar `.shape` 
ex:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
              [3, 4, 5]])

print(x.shape)
```

ainda se quiser pegar a transposta, ex:

```
print(x.T)
```

imprime:

```
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

boa diversão!

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
tam_matriz = (len(minha_matriz), len(minha_matriz[0]))
```

Isto vai dar um tuple, neste caso: `(2, 3)`

Podes imprimir assim:

```
print('{} x {}'.format(tam_matriz[0], tam_matriz[1]))
```

Ou com uma função:

```
def dimensoes(m):
    return (len(m), len(m[0]))

print(dimensoes(minha_matriz)) # (2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha eu fiz desta forma, não é a melhor, porém, funcional:`

```
def dimensoes(matriz):
colunas = 0
linhas = 0
qtd_colunas = 0
a = ''
for i in range(len(matriz)):
    linhas = linhas + 1 # soma a qtd de linhas
    colunas = matriz[i] # Armazena os itens de cada linha
for w in colunas: # Ira interar a qtd de itens da ->ÚLTIMA<- lista dentro da matriz.
    qtd_colunas = qtd_colunas + 1
a = print('{}X{}'.format(linhas, qtd_colunas))

return a
```